# Hide a javascript element - Not the common question

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, bootstrap-table

Sorry for the title, I don't even know how could I name the problem I have. I'm relative new with code and I don't know javascript. So I got a table, from creative-tim bootstrap table (this one: https://wenzhixin.github.io/fresh-bootstrap-table/compact-table.html)

I'm using python/flask and, everything is almost good. The problem is:

I need to hide that button on left bottom, that chooses how many rows the user want to see. I just want to see that 8 rows, but, what I could figure out is that I got the scripts that maybe do that job, by links, on the html archive, provided by creative-tim download:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>`

I know that because if I comment one of them, the button vanishes but I lot of things too.

I tried to find on these codes, the function that do that thing but I couldn't find.

I also, tried to get these codes and put on an local archive, and call them on the html, so that I could delete things to find the function but, even that, didn't work.

Can someone help me out here? Hide it or just make it stop working, is good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELETE `<span class="pagination-info"> </span>`
DELETE `<span class="btn-group dropdown dropup"></span>`

EDIT `<span class="page-list"> rows visible</span>` and say 8